# laravel api validation custom message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to write a custom message for a validation in laravel.
I have checked online and I saw some post where others solve that same issue by adding a protected function. I have also added the function to my code but it is not working. This is my code
This is myFormController.php:

> public function req(RegistrationRequest $request){   $validated =
>   $request->validated();
>           return $validated;  )}

This is the RegistrationRequest.php:

> use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;  use
>   Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException;
>
> public function authorize()
>       {
>           return true;
>       }
>
> ```
> public function rules()
> {
>     return [
>         'email' => 'required|email',
>         'firstname' => 'required|string|max:20',
>         'lastname' => 'required|string|max:50',
>         'password' => 'required|min:8',
>     ];
> }  protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator) {
> throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json($validator->errors(), 422)); }
> ```

When that did not work, I used this:

> protected function 
>   failedValidation(\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator 
>   $validator) {  throw new
>   \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException(response()->json($validator->errors(),
>   422)); }

Please what am I doing wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want custom messages just override `messages` method you just need to return an array containing key value pairs of `field_name => 'message'`

```php
/**
 * Get custom messages for validator errors.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function messages()
{
    return [
      'field_name.required' => 'field_name is requeired',
      'field_name.max' => 'max length should be something.'
    ];
}
```

Comment: I have gotten it, the error code 422 is the one causing the problem, everything worked well immediately I removed it